# Determine when the SSRS Report Viewer control has been re-rendered

Tags: reporting-services, client-side

I have a requirement to display certain Microsoft Report Viewer parameters as auto-complete textboxes instead of the standard drop-down lists. I've done this using jQuery-UI and all is fine until the 'View Report' button is clicked.
At this point, the parameter area is refreshed and I lose my changes.

I'm looking for an event that is fired after the parameter area or the complete report has been rebuilt.

**Answer**

I was applying my jQuery-UI functionality in the `$(document).ready()` function when I should have been applying it in the `pageLoad()` function. This function is also called for partial post-backs.

See [here](http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/).

Comment: Note that you can answer your own questions - and accept (after 24 hrs). This will make it a lot easier for others to find your solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of applying the jQuery-UI functionality in the $(document).ready() function, apply it in the ScriptManager pageLoad() function. This function is also called for partial post-backs.

See [here](http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/).